# Right way to setup wordpress base url

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, woocommerce, centos

We have site in first server at address example.com 
And second site in wordpress and in another server and now in different domain.

We want to attach second server to first server domain like example.com/shop

We try to do this but some urls in wordpress redirect to example.com (woocommerce ajax checkout)

How we can set fixed base url to wordpress as example.com/shop

> Blockquote The similar question
>   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155562/can-you-have-a-blog-in-a-subdirectory-hosted-on-a-different-server

Comment: What do you have for the second site's general settings? WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) should probably be `example.com/shop`.

Comment: Yes, I setup it

Comment: Please see this link:  https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214580498-How-do-I-change-the-WordPress-Site-URL-

Comment: @SavanDholu thanks, but i already done it.